# Setting location of document templates in SharePoint document library in Office 2010 applications

Tags: document-template, office-integration, document-library

One of the functionalities advertised for Office 2010 was that "People can access document templates stored in SharePoint 2010 via the New Document Wizard in Microsoft Office applications" (see page 26 in the PDF "[Business Productivity at Its Best: Office 2010 and SharePoint 2010](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/B/C/ABC977C1-8540-4A2F-9761-F5E5FD2BFC3D/SPProductivityatItsBestWhitePaper.pdf)).

However, I can't find a way to set this in Office 2010 applications.

I've looked at

1. Workgroup Templates (Word 2010 -> Backstory -> Options -> Advanced -> File Locations...) - I can't store URL or UNC paths - or even a mapped network drive to the SharePoint document library.
2. Trusted Locations (Word 2010 -> Backstory -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Trusted Locations -> Add new locations...) - "security reasons" disallow it. Would this need to be set through the Group Policies?

Anyhow, it seems that the functionality to have a master document library of corporate templates is not (yet?) available in Office 2010 with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the Document Library in SharePoint and in the Ribbon you will find an icon labled Connect to Office.  Once you "connect" a site to Office, it is added to a SharePoint list that is attached to your personal profile (you can find it in your MySite).  The next time you open an Office application, it will query this list which has two outcomes.  The first is that the Document Library will now appear in the Backstage under Save & Send | Save to SharePoint and the second is that you will see Templates associated with available Content Types for that Document Library when you click New in the Backstage.

Comment: Thanks Ryan... that's it. I just found out more details on how the Content Types are made available to Office 2010. http://www.endusersharepoint.com/EUSP2010/2010/07/01/consuming-sharepoint-content-types-in-office-2010/ It appears that the "Connect to Office" button in the ribbon (on the SharePoint site) adds the link to your MySite.

Comment: Is it possible to make these office templates available in New Document Wizard in Microsoft Office applications to all users of a company by policy? In our case, these are company wide templates. Otherwise, I guess less than 1% of the users will do these steps by themselves manually.